# Merge tags [xamarin.forms] and [xamarin-forms]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

Both these tags relate to the same Xamarin cross-platform API.

There are currently 67 questions tagged in the [xamarin-forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xamarin-forms) tag and 683 in the [xamarin.forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xamarin.forms)

The tag [xamarin.forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xamarin.forms) is more correct as that is how the API is referenced.

Having the duplicated tag adds confusion.

Answer (score 5):

This seems to be perfectly sensible to me. Just look at the wiki page for [xamarin-forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xamarin-forms) "With the Xamarin.Forms API you ca..." even the wiki pages already agrees with you on this one.

The site does already offer a way to propose [synonyms](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xamarin.forms/synonyms) but you need a 'score of five' within that tag to be able to do so.

Answer (score 4):

I have retagged the 67 questions with the [xamarin-forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xamarin-forms) tag to [xamarin.forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xamarin.forms). To prevent people from continuing to use the old tag, it will need to be removed and a synonym will need to be put in place. Unfortunately, that is not something I can do.

Comment: There are two possibilities: 1. There should be a synonym, thus re-tagging was useless. 2. The tag should just die, thus a synonym would be useless. As it stands, I tend to the second one. As an aside, if two tags shall just be merged without any other action, mods can do it fast without re-activating any questions.

Comment: @Deduplicator: Mods, not devs? Just want to make sure I got it for future reference, since mods *can't* burninate any more efficiently than J Random 2ker. (Consistency? wHat's thaT/)

Comment: Well, merging tags isn't as destructive as simply killing one off. And yes, mods can do the former, but not the latter.

Comment: Thanks @Michael Irigoyen for retagging.