# The [Xamarin-Forms] tag should be merged with [Xamarin.Forms]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

This request has been made once already: [Merge tags [xamarin.forms] and [xamarin-forms]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289887/merge-tags-xamarin-forms-and-xamarin-forms) , and everyone pretty much agreed that a change is necessary but that was almost a year ago and the two tags still co-exist.

Currently the description for [xamarin-forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xamarin-forms) reads:

> Xamarin.Forms is a cross-platform UI toolkit that allows developers to easily create native user interface layouts that can be shared across Android, iOS, and Windows Phone.

And the description for [xamarin.forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xamarin.forms) is this:

> Xamarin.Forms is a Xamarin product allowing the build native UIs for iOS, Android, and Windows Phone from a single, shared C# (and Xaml codebase optional).

So the tags are literally identical and even though the difference in questions asked [xamarin.forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xamarin.forms) (1,887) to [xamarin-forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xamarin-forms) (164) is really big, I still think that there should not be any confusion about what tag to use. This is also more annoying for anybody that actually wants to help people, since they have to look at multiple tags to see all questions regarding Xamarin.Forms.

The Xamarin community is not really a big one at the moment so I think its a shame that it is split even further by such a minor detail.

Comment: Merging seems perfectly appropriate to me. You need a moderator to do that. Avoid mentioning "burnination." It is not required here.

Comment: @CodyGray thanks, i wasnt exactly sure wheter burnination or retagging was appropriate

Comment: One of them should be a synonym of the other. In terms of tag correctness usually `-` denotes a space so which is it, is it `Xamarin Forms` or `Xamarin.Forms`? *Based on your post would say that [tag:xamarin-forms] should be a [synonym](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/xamarin.forms/synonyms) of [tag:xamarin.forms].*

Comment: @Lankymart: Yes, the official product name is Xamarin.Forms, with the period.