# Can it be appropriate to edit a tags descriptions saying "Please use this other tag"?

Tags: discussion, tags

There have been multiple requests (most recently by me: [The [Xamarin-Forms] tag should be merged with [Xamarin.Forms]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318447/the-xamarin-forms-tag-should-be-merged-with-xamarin-forms), but also by other people: [Merge tags [xamarin.forms] and [xamarin-forms]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289887/merge-tags-xamarin-forms-and-xamarin-forms?lq=1)) to merge [xamarin.forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xamarin.forms) with [xamarin-forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xamarin-forms).

And in both posts everyone seemed to agree, that merging the tags looks reasonable, but alas, nothing has happened so far.

This is still mildly annoying to me, so i thought of submitting an edit to the description of the tag saying something like "Please do not use this tag, use Xamarin.Forms for better visibility."

Would that be appropriate?

Comment: Well, let's hope that third time does it. We just need a mod to stumble over it now...

Comment: There are [two new moderators](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318714/please-welcome-our-new-stack-overflow-moderators?cb=1) who probably need some practice using the tag merge feature. But yeah, there needs to be a better system for this.